# Piping to vim vs vim -

Tags: help-system

When I pipe text to vim I discovered that by using:

```
cat somefile | vim -
```

it works properly, whereas:

```
cat somefile | vim
```

makes a mess of the code. For example, type:

```
cat test.pl | vim
```

where test.pl is:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    # i like comments
    say "This line, and the next one, should not be comments"
done
```

and you end up with:

```
le true
do
    # i like comments
    #     say "This line, and the next one, should not be comments"
    #     done
    #
```

It's as if without the hyphen the text appears as if it's being typed, switching modes and extending comments when you press enter etc, whereas with the hyphen it's treated as if a filename containing the piped text was passed to vim.  I cannot locate the relevant help on this.  I'm pretty sure it's not a shell feature (I'm using Bash on a Red Hat box).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a shell feature, but a common convention for command-line tools to interpret `-` argument as an instruction to read data from standard input. Your understanding of how it works is correct.

For documentation see [`:help --`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#--):

> `-`
>
> This argument can mean two things, depending on whether Ex mode is to be used.
>
> Starting in Normal mode:
>
> ```
> vim -
> ex -v -
> ```
>
> Start editing a new buffer, which is filled with text
>   that is read from stdin.  The commands that would normally be
>   read from stdin will now be read from stderr.  Example:
>
> ```
> find . -name "*.c" -print | vim -
> ```
>
> The buffer will be marked modified, because it contains text
>   that needs to be saved.  Except when in readonly mode, then
>   the buffer is not marked modified.  Example:
>
> ```
> ls | view -
> ```

Case with `stderr` being used as a source of commands is quite unusual, so
here's an example that demonstrates how it works:

```
$ ls
commands  input
$ cat -A commands
wcwwas^[wgUE:w output$
$ cat input
This is input text.
$ cat input | vim - 2< commands
Vim: Reading from stdin...
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: Finished.
$ ls
commands  input  output
$ cat output
This was INPUT text.
```

(Not sure why it says "error reading input".)

Comment: You beat me to the punch by about 15 seconds :(

Comment: I'm marking your answer correct, but I find that help very confusing. I have no idea what it's talking about with the "..read from stderr" thing. I just did a find within /tmp and got permission denied which i can redirect via 2>err.txt and confirm it's writing to stderr but I see no such text inside vim when using | vim -.

Comment: @DrEval Try this: https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/12/24/piping-into-vim-and-io-tidbits/ The way I read that, it's not reading output sent to stderr. It's reading input from it.

Comment: @DrEval, see my edit for an example with `stderr`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've explained what's happening quite well yourself!

The documentation for this can be found at `:help --`.

In general, help for Vim's command line arguments is at `:help vim-arguments`, with help for e.g. the specific argument `-X` at `:help -X`. Because `:help -` is unfortunately already occupied, an extra hyphen is added in this instance.

Comment: Yeah, I did search for help but there was no way I'd have known to type hyphen twice! Thanks!